# Why can't OS's keep audio and video recording in sync?

Tags: operating-systems, real-time

It seems every program that purports to record webcams fails to keep audio and video in sync.  Moreover, there are probably man millenia being spent by people trying to correct for this during editing.

While it is understandable that OS's may have to buffer incoming raw audio and video prior to compression, if necessary taking gigabytes of RAM, it is less understandable that they can't keep the two in sync during recording.

This points to an architectural flaw in common with the major OSs.  What is the problem?

Comment: "It seems every program..." Some examples, please.

Comment: The webcam is Microsoft's, and the software I've tried includes Microsoft's default camera app, Zoom conference recording and OBS .  At the very least one would expect MS to understand how to write an app for their own OS using their own webcam.

Comment: How does a flaw in one app on one OS point to "an architectural flaw with the major OSs"? If multiple apps have a problem it would point to a fault in the common part, which is the web cam.

Comment: It was 3 apps but the point about one OS and one web cam is well taken and would render the question moot were it not for the fact that, A) it was a web cam provided by the OS provider and B) during searches for solutions, the many references to the synchronization problem and its solutions never referred to a common webcam.

The most reasonable critique of my question is that it may simply be MS's OS but even so, that is a rather significant OS.

Comment: Oops... Looks like Linux has the problem as well, and there is a product you can buy to compensate for it:

https://developer.ridgerun.com/wiki/index.php?title=USB_Camera